# search for comments on a page posted with facebook api

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a testing page on my site that simply lets users login. Once logged in, you can post a comment on the page (testpage.php). I am able to get the graph of the posted comments, but how do I search through those comments. I want to make a page where anyone can search through comments on testpage.php and all comments that match what was searched for would appear. how would I go about doing this? I have already looked over the facebook developement pages but they do not go into the details I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the Graph API page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (look for the Searching section) you cannot use the API to search for comments directly. You would have to get all the posts using the Graph API then perform your search separately.